# How to write instant queries in prometheus adapter to get custom metric value from prometheus operator?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-java

I want to continuously monitor a custom metric(of metricType Gauge) implemented in java usinf prometheus and autoscale the kubernetes pod based on that value. The value is exposed in the prometheus dashboard and I can able to access in the rest - http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query= . The tutorials are available only for series query (for prometheus adapter) and I want to implement instant query in prometheus adapter to monitor this metric, because if I use series query, I get a custom metric value in milli"s instead of integers. Current prometheus-adapter.yaml configuration.

```
rules:
  default: false
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"<custom-metric>"}'
    resources: { template: "<<.Resource>>" }
    name:
      matches: "custom-metric"
      as: "custom-metric"
prometheus:
  url: http://prom-demo-prometheus-opera-prometheus<namespace>
  port: port
```

Can anyone let me know how to implement this?
Thanks in advance!